# Character wants a zero arguments constructor

Tags: java

I'm going crazy! Isn't the `Character` constructor supposed to get e `char` argument?

Why when I try to compile this, it gives me a compile error:

```
public class TestClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    char c = 'a';
    Character cObj = new Character(c);
  } 
}
```

The error is:

```
TestClass.java:5: error: constructor Character in class Character cannot be applied to given types;
    Character cObj = new Character(c);
                 ^
  required: no arguments
  found: char
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Also, if I try to compile this:

```
public class TestClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    char c = 'a';
    Character cObj = Character.valueOf(c);
  } 
}
```

I get:

```
TestClass.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    Character cObj = Character.valueOf(c);
                          ^
  symbol:   method valueOf(char)
  location: class Character
1 error
```

This is happening on macOS Sierra 10.12.6 with the latest Oracle java version "1.8.0_144".

If I try to compile the same code on Linux using OpenJDk 8, all compiles as it should.

What am I missing?

Comment: My guess is that you're (accidentally) not using `java.lang.Character`, but another `Character` class that you've written yourself somewhere. The code you've written works fine on its own. (Admittedly it would be simpler to just use autoboxing: `Character cObj = 'a';`.)

Comment: That's my guess too, but I have not written any `Caracter` class o_O. Also, autoboxing doesn't compile too...

Comment: I suggest you look for a file called `Character.class` somewhere on your classpath. And show the compiler error you get for autoboxing. (I'd try similar things with `Integer` etc just to find out how pervasive it is.)

Comment: For fun (and debugging), you can do a `System.out.println(Character.getClass().getCanonicalName())` to see which Character you are actual constructing.

Answer (score 0):

since java supports boxing primitives to wrapper class you can just do

```
Character cObj = 'a';
```

or

```
char c = 'a';
Character cObj = c;
```

but this eventhoe is not necessary have to work

```
char c = 'a';
Character cObj = new Character(c);
```

be sure you are importing the right [Class java.lang.Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)

Comment: Doesn't work either. It rather looks like something is messed up in my classpath...

Comment: check please the package... and clean the project